# PyCassa - ColumnFamily.get() - Now what?

Tags: python, cassandra, pycassa

Sorry if this seems like a dumb question, but I can't find an answer anywhere.

I have a column family with a comparator type of "TimeUUIDType"

I can do inserts to it no problem, and I can also do gets on on without any issue and see my results be shown.

What I am really lost on here, is after I perform a get() what exactly am I getting back? Is it an array of values?

If someone could show me how I might ever go about doing a simple loop to loop through my results, that would be a massive help!

When I do a get, the results are in the following format in terminal :

(key) -> (Column : value) (Column: value) (Column: value)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you post a copy or example of your table schema? That would help zone in on the right answers for your particular use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If memory serves, you get back a tuple of

```
(key<string>, OrderedDict{column_name: column_value})
```

So, if you want to go over each column, you would do something like

```
for column_name, column_value in cf.get(...)[1].items():
    print column_name, column_value
```

**EDIT / CORRECTION **

The return value from a get() is only the columns, not the key and columns.

```
for column_name, column_value in cf.get(...).items():
    print column_name, column_value
```

I was thinking of multiget / get_range which include them as you are potentially returning more than a single row.  Thanks @thobbs for pycassa and the correction.

Comment: Thanks - but as I said above, I am using TimeUUIDTypes for my columns, which causes problems I don't actually know the name of any given column, you know how I might get around that?

Comment: @Slippy what are you trying to do that iterating over the results doesn't solve?  Also, to make a minor correction to sberry's answer, only the columns are returned from get(), not a tuple of the key and columns.

Comment: @TylerHobbs - I am trying to get all of the value back so I can use them, but my column names are TimeUUIDs - so at any point I don't know what the column is called in order to get the values.

Comment: @TylerHobbs, sberry - I was being an idiot - I read the response and thought you meant "column_name" and "column_value" where they are mine, but the actual usage of column_name and column_value works because that is what they ARE in the results. Thanks!